# Extract f-statistic from multiple variable regression model and intercorrelated variables

Tags: r, regression, classification, statistical-significance

I'm currently analyzing some microarray data (gene expression) and I'm running the kNN classification algorithm on them.

Data consisted from 920 different genes and 8 different observations (with 5 replications each).

At the beginning I just ran the kNN algorithm on the training data and then in order to improve the results I thought what if I could find which of these 920 variables (genes) in the training set are more significant in a linear regression model. Then I wrote the following code to extract the f-statistic  of each gene and then filter out the ones that have for example f-statistic value < 1 and finally run the kNN algorithm with the new data.

```
# initialize a numeric vector to store fstatistic
fstat = as.numeric(rep(NA, times = 920))
names(fstat) = names(train_set[-921])
i = 1 
# Calculate the f-statistic for each variable
for (k in names(train_set[,-921])){

  formula = as.formula(paste(k , "~ train_set$classes" )  )
  lm_1 = lm(formula , data = train_set)
  fstat[i] = summary(lm_1)$fstatistic[1]

  i = i + 1
}
insignificant_names = names(which(sort(fstat, decreasing = T) < 1))
```

To be honest I'm not sure if this idea/thought is correct and please let me know your opinion and any suggestions.

Also another thing that i would like to mention is that genes are not isolated from each other and the expression level of one affects many others. So by checking in the linear model above one by one might not be the best way to figure out the significant of genes. If that statement sounds reasonable, is there any way to take into account such relations in the linear modeling procedure ?

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Nah. Nothing yet. I'm looking at literature in case to find something.